# Notificaciones Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

¿Como encender la pantalla de el móvil cuando una aplicacion movil lanza una notificacion?

Mi aplicación lanza este tipo de notificaciones dependiendo parámetros especifico, quiero que aparte de vibrar y sonar encienda también la pantalla, que pena si no me he hecho entender.

```
public void carrera(int id, int iconid, String titulo, String contenido) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MapsActivity.this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(iconid)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.mipmap.poder_amarillo))
                    .setContentTitle(titulo)
                    .setContentIntent(contIntent)
                    .setSound((Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.vip)))
                    //.setVibrate(new long[]{ 1000,500,1000,800,1000,1500 })
                    .setLights(Color.RED,3000,3000)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setContentText(contenido);
    notificacion.notify(id, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Por favor, actualiza la pregunta. Revisa este [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
Saludos

Comment: Hola David. A parte de visitar los enlaces que te comenta @Mauricio es recomendable que publiques lo que hayas intentado, aunque no funcione, para poder ayudarte de manera más específica :) y aclarar un poquito la pregunta.

Comment: Y este codigo que comportamiento tiene

Comment: Bueno esta es la notificación en android studio, cuando esta notificación sea llamada la pantalla debe encenderse. pensé que era mas sencillo y he investigado en Internet, como pueden ver usa prioridad máxima y visibility public, pero ninguna de estas opciones me encienden la pantalla. ¿que opcion puedo usar?

Comment: @DavidPeña es importante que en tus preguntas agregues más información ya que algunas tienden a ser muy abiertas, saludos!

Comment: por que no pruebas con onesignal , es una pagina que te brinda una api para ponerle a tu app y manejar las notificaciones por ahi, con calendarios y programadas, es mucho mejor que codificar todo lo que estas haciendo, ya que con solo 3 lineas de codigo integras un sistema de push notifications entero ! :)

Comment: Estoy leyendo la documentación, interesante les comentare como me fue.

Comment: Armando muchas gracias por recomendarme onesignal. pero no es exactamente lo que estoy buscando, si te das cuenta estoy hablando de una notificación predeterminada que ya tiene sus parámetros establecidos, mi aplicaciones realiza cálculos especifico y dependiendo de esos cálculos arroja una notificación al usuario. lo único que quiero adicionarle es el permiso de encender la pantalla. :)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta encender la pantalla con este codigo:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire(3000);
wl.release();
```

y agrega al manifest el siguiente permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Buena idea, voy a probar

Comment: Te funcionó?, o que otra forma descubriste he intentado con lo que se mencionó y nada